# How can I get my typescript test to recognise JSX?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm working on an ASP.NET core project with a typescript front-end. I want to write tests for the typescript using Mocha, Chai and Mockito (since I want to test React components, I think I also need Enzyme). On running `npm test` I get errors at the first '<' in the line `const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;`

The test file is a .tsx and is referenced in the package.json as

```
"mocha": { 
    "extension": [ "ts", "tsx" ], 
    "spec": "wwwroot/ts-tests/**/*.test.tsx"
}
```

and in the tsconfig.json as

```
"include": ["./wwwroot/ts-tests/**/*.test.tsx"]
```

The test file is as follows:

```
describe('Rendering',
    () => {
        it('should show header',
            () => {
                const rootContainer = document.createElement('div');
                const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
                ReactDOM.render(element, rootContainer);
            });
    }
)
```

I think I've narrowed the problem down to the fact that node.js isn't recognising JSX because running tests with only javascript in works fine and the tsx is being transpiled into js fine as well.

Any ideas? I'd prefer not to keep adding more new modules if I can help it

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mocha. Wraps [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) which supports tsx

Comment: Yep, but no luck, the problem persists